# SQLite LIKE not using index

Tags: sqlite

The question [sqlite not using index with like query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994870/sqlite-not-using-index-with-like-query) is the closest I could find, but I am already using the latest version of SQLite:

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30 fc49f556e48970561d7ab6a2f24fdd7d9eb81ff2
```

The table is really simple:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, size INTEGER NOT NULL, path TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_id ON test(id);
CREATE INDEX idx_size ON test(size);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_path ON test(path);
```

I insert data from a folder scan and then I try to seach using LIKE:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE "%Caprice%";
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE test
```

I have tried using NVARCHAR (path is UTF-8 string), adding COLLATE NOCASE to path, turning PRAGMA case_sensitive_like ON and OFF, but whatever I do it insists on using SCAN instead of SEARCH.

Any clues as to what I may be doing wrong are more than welcome.

**EDIT:**

Let me clarify that I also tried using:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE "Caprice%";
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE test
```

As well as:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE "Caprice";
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE test
```

But as you can see it simply refuses to use the index.

**EDIT2:**

[The answer you are referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423387/can-the-like-statement-be-optimized-to-not-do-full-table-scans) is what I was looking for, but the question title is so verbose that I would probably never come up with the right search terms to find it. Thanks.

Comment: Usually indexes can't be used for searching in the middle of the word. It's different if you're searching from the beginning.

Comment: I tried also "Caprice%" and just "Caprice" but it still does not use SEARCH as long as there is a LIKE clause in SELECT. Any ideas?

Comment: Also if there is not much data it is faster to scan the table than to go through an index

Comment: And what would be the threshold for "not much data"?

Comment: Another online source suggests:  (1) `LIKE` operators cannot use indices unless the index is case insensitive.  Use `GLOB` for case sensitive fields. (2) `LIKE` and `GLOB` operators cannot use indices if the pattern 
begins with a wildcard.   (3) Nothing in SQLite will use an index if you are connecting terms using `OR`.